# My If/Then formula is not working

Tags: calculated-column-formula

Here is the statement I used:   =IF([State]=OH, "[PRAC Comm]*0.05", "0").

What I am trying to do is calculate an amount based on the state.  If the state is OH, then I need to multiply the amount in the PRAC Comm column by 5%, If the state is anything else, then I need it to put in a zero amount.

Thanks

Comment: What exactly is happening that this is not working? Is the value not coming out in the way you expect or are you actually receiving an error from SharePoint?

Comment: I'm receiving an error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose `State` field is a text or choice & `PRAC Comm` is a number , so the formula should be like below, please try it and let me know

```
IF([State]="OH",([PRAC Comm]*0.05),0)
```

Comment: Thank you sooo much!  That worked!  I needed to leave out the quotation marks where I put them and add them where I didn't.